# how to change editcontrol with function?

Tags: c++, mfc

hello guys I was plc programmer just trying to start C++ programmer

I am trying to convert to this code to function

```
m_file.Open(posText[7], CStdioFile::modeRead);
m_file.ReadString(posValue[7]);
UpdateData(TRUE);
dlg.s_PostionZ2 = posValue[7];
UpdateData(FALSE);
m_file.Close();
```

and this my function but it didn't work

```
void mainDial::opeFile(CString path, CString value, CString location)
{
    slaveDialog dlg;
    m_file.Open(path, CStdioFile::modeRead);
    m_file.ReadString(value);
    AfxMessageBox(location);
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    location = value;
    UpdateData(FALSE);
    m_file.Close();
}
```

what I am trying to do is just open a file and save to value and change location value

the problem is the location is in the other dialog (SlaveDialog dlg;)

it is ok by just simply enter dlg.S_position

but if I want it to do with using a function to pass the location like this

```
opeFile(posText[0], posValue[0], _T("dlg.s_PostionX1"));

or

opeFile(posText[0], posValue[0], dlg.s_PostionX1);
```

it didn't work both way so how can I change to my function work

thank you for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I am trying to do is just open a file and save to value and change location value

You are passing in the function's output parameters *by value*, so they make *copies* of the caller's values. Any changes the function makes to the parameters is done to the *copies* and not reflected back to the caller.

To do what you want, you need to pass in the output parameters *by reference* instead, eg:

```
void mainDial::opeFile(CString path, CString& value, CString& location)
```

Comment: and it worked really well and now I know why it happen
 you are super good man! thanks

Comment: I can't vote cuz I am a new but i do accept hope you had a great day